# NoClassDefFoundError: org/eclipse/jetty/io/ByteBufferPool when using DropWizard

Tags: java, maven, jetty, dropwizard

I am currently trying to run the getting started application of dropwizard (http://dropwizard.io/getting-started.html). I can manage to build the jar file using mvn package but when I run the file ( java -jar target/my-project-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar ) I get an error :

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:
   org/eclipse/jetty/io/ByteBufferPool
```

Here is my pom.xml :

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

<groupId>com.example</groupId>
<artifactId>my-project</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.dropwizard</groupId>
        <artifactId>dropwizard-core</artifactId>
        <version>${dropwizard.version}</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<properties>
    <!-- use UTF-8 for everything -->
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
    <dropwizard.version>0.7.0</dropwizard.version>
</properties>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.1</version>
            <!-- compile for Java 1.7 -->
            <configuration>
                <source>1.7</source>
                <target>1.7</target>
                <encoding>UTF-8</encoding>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>1.6</version>
        <configuration>
        <createDependencyReducedPom>true</createDependencyReducedPom>
        <filters>
            <filter>
            <artifact>*:*</artifact>
            <excludes>
                <exclude>META-INF/*.SF</exclude>
                <exclude>META-INF/*.DSA</exclude>
                <exclude>META-INF/*.RSA</exclude>
            </excludes>
            </filter>
        </filters>
        </configuration>
        <executions>
        <execution>
            <phase>package</phase>
            <goals>
            <goal>shade</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
            <transformers>
                <transformer implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.ServicesResourceTransformer"/>
                <transformer implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.ManifestResourceTransformer">
                <mainClass>com.example.helloworld.HelloWorldApplication</mainClass>
                </transformer>
            </transformers>
            </configuration>
        </execution>
        </executions>
    </plugin>
    <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.4</version>
        <configuration>
        <archive>
            <manifest>
            <addDefaultImplementationEntries>true</addDefaultImplementationEntries>
            </manifest>
        </archive>
        </configuration>
    </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

I don't have too much experience with maven configuration so I don't see anything wrong. All of my sources seem to be in the right places as well. Thanks for any suggestion you may have.

**Edit :**

After adding the suggestion of OF399991 to the pom I noticed a warning (that was already there but not as clearly) when running mvn package or install :

```
[WARNING] The POM for org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-server:jar:9.0.7.v20131107 is invalid,
transitive dependencies (if any) will not be available: 1 problem was encountered while 
building the effective model for org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-server:9.0.7.v20131107

[FATAL] Non-parseable POM /home/yenox/.m2/repository/org/eclipse/jetty/jetty-
parent/20/jetty-parent-20.pom: end tag name </body> must match start tag name <hr> from 
line 5 (position: TEXT seen ...</center>\r\n</body>... @6:8)  @ 
/home/yenox/.m2/repository/org/eclipse/jetty/jetty-parent/20/jetty-parent-20.pom, line 6, 
column 8
```

Comment: Have you tried to install using Maven yet?

Comment: You mean on another project ? Not on this machine, no.

Comment: Ok, the build is not gonna do much. I think you need to run install on this to get the dependencies

Comment: I did do a mvn install on this project though.

Comment: So if that's already installed, you should post the actual code you have made on there. The problem may not necessarily have to do with the pom file..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I ended up deleting the folder containing the dependencies in .m2/repository, then did a mvn clean install and everything went back to normal.

**Edit :**
I think I know where the error came from: I used maven2 at first, before switching to maven3 and it probably messed up my repository.

Answer (score 1):

You need to make sure the jar you build with maven contains all the dropwizard libraries. I suggest you examine the jar file you have build to see if it contains these.

If it doesn't then you need to add something like this to your pom.xml file between the  tags:

```
   <plugin>
     <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.4</version>
        <configuration>
        <archive>
        <manifest>
           <mainClass>com.wibblewobble</mainClass>
        </manifest>
        </archive>
        <descriptorRefs>
              <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
         </descriptorRefs>
         </configuration>
         <executions>
             <execution>
             <id>make-assembly</id>
             <phase>package</phase>
             <goals>
             <goal>single</goal>
             </goals>
             </execution>
        </executions>
        </plugin>
```

Then build the jar with something like this:

```
mvn package assembly:single
```

You will probably get two jars but the jar you will want to run will be called something like wibblewobble-1.0-jar-with-dependencies.

Comment: I still have the error but when trying your solution I noticed a warning displayed several times. I put it in the edit.